# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of Selfadjoint Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to show the following:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Suppose that $\|Tx\| = \|T\|$ for some unit vector $x \in H$ and for some bounded self-adjoint operator *T* on *H*. Then *x* is an eigenvector for $T^2$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\|T\|^2\; (= \|T^2\|)$. Moreover, either $Tx = \|T\| x$ or $Tx = \|T\| y$, where $y = \|T\| x - Tx$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @cmk I tried looking at $T^2x$, however, I was not really sure how to follow up with this. Then I tried finding the eigenvalues by setting $T^2 - \lambda I = 0$, but was unable to get a solution. Is there another angle I should look at?

Comment: This is a suggestion:

Since $T$ is self-adjoint
$\|T\|=\sup_{|x|=1}|Tx|=\sup_{|x|=1}|(Tx,x)|$
In your case, you have a solution over $\{v:|v|=1\}$ for
$\sup_{|x|=1|}(T^2x,x)=\|T\|^2=\|T^2\|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T^2$ is also self adjoint and so,
$$
\sup_{\|v\|=1}|(T^2v,v)|=\sup_{|v|=1}\|T^2v\|
$$

The $x$ in your problem is a solution to this optimization problem. Incidentally,  $\|T^2\|=\|T\|^2$.

Set $\lambda=\|T\|$. It follows that
\begin{aligned}
0&\leq \|T^2x-\lambda^2x\|^2=\|T^2x\|^2-2\lambda^2(T^2x,x)+\lambda^4\|x\|^2\\
&\leq \|T^2\|^2 -2\lambda^4+\lambda^4\\
&=\lambda^4-\lambda^4=0
\end{aligned}

The conclusion to your problem should follow from looking at 
$$
0=(T^2-\lambda^2 I)x=(T-\lambda I)(T+\lambda I)x
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$\|T\|^2 = \|Tx\|^2 = |\langle Tx,Tx\rangle| = |\langle T^2x,x\rangle| \stackrel{CS}{\le} \|T^2x\|\|x\| \le \|T\|^2\|x\|^2 = \|T\|^2$$

The equality condition implies there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $T^2x = \alpha x$.

We have
$$\|T\|^2 = \|Tx\|^2 = \langle Tx,Tx\rangle =\langle T^2x,x\rangle = \langle \alpha x,x\rangle = \alpha\|x\|^2 = \alpha$$
so $T^2x = \|T\|^2x$.

Comment: I was trying to do what you did on the first line, and couldn't quite get there. Nice.